# Он понял это(,) только когда очнулся и увидел море

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, будьте добры, нужна ли запятая: 
Он понял это(,) только когда очнулся и увидел море.

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, нажмите на треугольник рядом с ним, а также на галочку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, запятая нужна: слова типа *только* "перетягивают" запятую в позицию перед собой. Верно:

> Он понял это, только когда очнулся и увидел море.